# Synonymize [alphavantage] to [alphavantage-api]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

- Both ([alphavantage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alphavantage) and [alphavantage-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alphavantage-api)) refer to the same API.
- The wiki and excerpt are better at [alphavantage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alphavantage), and it is better to move it to [alphavantage-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alphavantage-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of pointless prefixes or suffixes in tags, including "-api". This is a programming Q&A site; everyone can already assume that the questions are about the API.

Also, since it looks like the name of the product is two words ("Alpha Vantage"), I've gone ahead to hyphenate the tag, which is our customary representation for spaces.

[alpha-vantage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alpha-vantage) ← [alphavantage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alphavantage)
[alpha-vantage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alpha-vantage) ← [alphavantage-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alphavantage-api)